# How to use reduce to find element and build array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, reduce

Trying to write logic if object path are same it should create one object in the array with `name` comma separated, How to use reduce to achieve this task ?

main.js

```
 var data = [
{id: "param", name: "IGetRefillMultiPlanParam", path: "@combinator-interfaces/dist/drug/GetRefills/GetRefills.Model.ts"}
{id: "details", name: "IRefills", path: "@combinator-interfaces/dist/drug/GetRefills/GetRefills.Model.ts"}
{id: "header", name: "IHeader", path: "@combinator-interfaces/dist/common/Header.Model.ts"}
]

    function buildInterface (data) {
           var interfaceArray = [];
           data.reduce(function(acc,arr){
            var filePath = acc.path.replace('.ts','');
            var imports  = data.map(d => d.name).join(', '); 
                if(acc.path.includes(arr.path)) {
                interfaceArray.push(`import { ${imports} } from '${filePath}';\n\n`);
                }
            });

            return interfaceArray;

       }
```

Expected Result

```
[
    'import { IGetRefillMultiPlanParam, IRefills} from "@combinator-interfaces/dist/drug/GetRefills/GetRefills.Model"',
    'import { IHeader } from "@combinator-interfaces/dist/common/Header.Model"'
]
```

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? Why did you ask this question?

Comment: @Andreas its throwing error `i Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: I don't think you know how to use `reduce` yet. Also, can you explain your algorithm in English? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @slider expected result is there to understand what i am trying to achieve , i know i don't have knowledge about reduce trying to learn, basically if objects have same path it should create one import object with the names in the imports.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem statement. But I'm not sure if I understand your approach to solving it based on the code you've pasted. That's why it may help in clarifying your high level approach in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using `reduce` wrong. Take a look at this and if you have any questions ask.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "param",
    name: "IGetRefillMultiPlanParam", 
    path: "@combinator-interfaces/dist/drug/GetRefills/GetRefills.Model.ts"
  },
  {
    id: "details",
    name: "IRefills", 
    path: "@combinator-interfaces/dist/drug/GetRefills/GetRefills.Model.ts"
  },
  {
    id: "header",
    name: "IHeader", 
    path: "@combinator-interfaces/dist/common/Header.Model.ts"
  },
];

function buildInterface (data) {
  const parsed = data.reduce((map, importing) => {
    if (!map[importing.path]) {
      map[importing.path] = [];
    }
    const list = map[importing.path];
    
    list.push(importing.name);
    
    return map;
  }, {});
  console.log('parsed', parsed);
  
  return Object.entries(parsed).map(([importPath, toImport]) => {
    return `import { ${toImport.join(', ')} } from '${importPath.replace('.ts','')}'`;
  });
}
console.log(buildInterface(data));
```

Comment: Thank you Boss solved my problem! Still scratching my head how did you do that :) will figure it out. thanks again

Comment: The way the reduce function is used here is to me the most common. This is the most readable way to convert array to object of some sort.